# Invisible energy in a particle collision

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider

I read a lot about the so-called "missing" energy in hadronic collisions. I always thought that it was mainly due to neutrinos and also nuclear deformations, but today I read that "on average, 30% of the energy is missing in a hadronic collision", where is all this energy going?

Comment: you should give a link for context

Comment: Why can't 30% be due to neutrinos? Semileptonic decays of heavy quarks have high branching fractions.

Comment: If the quotation from the unspecified source is talking about "the energy" $\sqrt s$ as opposed to the **transverse** energy, it could also be including (near-)collinear particles that 'escape' down the beam pipe.